# How to refresh EntityFramework core 5 model or query filter cache?

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-5

I have this query filter on tenant:

```
m.Builder.HasQueryFilter(mm => EF.Property<int>(mm, "TenantId") == SindikatDataSetBase.TenantId);
```

When I login into a desktop app as a different user static variable SindikatDataSetBase.TenantId changes, but the query filter still uses the previous TenantId value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it is bad to use static variable. EF Core supports variables in filters if they are part of `DbContext`

Create property in your `DbContext` TenantId and initialize, for example in constructor or using default initialization.

```cs
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
   public int TenantId { get; set; } = SindikatDataSetBase.TenantId;

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
      modelBuilder.Entity<SomeEntity>()
        .HasQueryFilter(mm => EF.Property<int>(mm, "TenantId") == TenantId);
   }
}
```

After that each new `MyDbContext` will catch your static variable and EF can create correct query.

**UPDATE**

How to avoid configuring parametrized QueryFilter inside `DbContext`

Idea is simple - mimic that we are already in DbContext's metod.

```cs
MyDbContext ctx = null;
m.Builder.HasQueryFilter(mm => EF.Property<int>(mm, "TenantId") == ctx.TenantId);
```

Comment: I would like to know of a better solution for my case that does not use a static variable. What comes to mind, in that case, is that I would suppose to use a dynamic variable that gets the value every time and that is not good for performance, not a better option. Logically when the user logs in you should keep those most common static values for that user in memory for best performance. Why constantly get values from DB that do not change, especially if they are very small? I see no benefits.

Comment: The downside of this answer is that then I need to move query filter definitions from IEntityTypeConfiguration to OnModelCreating, but I'll do that if there is no other option.

Comment: And you have to. Otherwise it will not work. Believe me, I'm a not a novice in LINQ translation. If you need technical depths of such problem I can find time and explain why it works only with DbContext properties.

Comment: BTW do you know how to have a shadow property "Builder.Property(typeof(int), "TenantId").HasDefaultValue()" and tell EF not to get it from the database on insert and update? I need to set HasDefaultValue because it is generated in the database but I do not need it to be fetched from the database. ValueGeneratedNever() does not work. Again for performance.

Comment: Updated with better solution. Your thoughts about performance... You really don't know how LINQ provider works.

Comment: I was not talking about LINQ but generally about static variables and you probably were not talking about static variables in general but in the context of EF. I am doing what makes sense to me and having a static variable is viable to me, it does not work because of conventions they choose to have for EF. It is not that it's a wrong thing because they choose to implement it in one way, that is how I see it. They are doing ti a bit strict to try to lower mistakes and bugs. If you create it too flexible then you are opening a door for numerous unpredicted bugs.

Comment: If I have a need and there is no other way that satisfies my needs then that does not make my needs wrong. There are clear and undoubtfully performance issues, maybe too small for many to bother but it is there and it does exist, essentially it's unnecessary in my case to select TenantId every time I do an insert, I don't need it and if there is a way to resolve this I'll gladly use it, and if not, I'll use it as is and make peace with it. ;)

Comment: Essentially, always wanting more, better, and more flexible moves us forward. There is not ultimate, fixed, final solution, the universe is not that restricted. Haha.

Comment: "You really don't know how LINQ provider works." I would rather hear a solution and/or an argument. These types of accusations do not help. Instead, rather show me how EF TenantId return is better for me and what do I gain. ;)

Comment: Selecting non-static variable is nothing in comparison to what EF should do to run your query. Do you know that for translating query it do a lot of things including compiling mapper. Second run is faster, but it also needs time for executing GetHashCode for whole expression tree, then if bucket is found, it runs Equals for whole expression tree, only then it runs compiled parameter accessors to retrieve parameters, even worse, they are boxed. Shortly, it is not part that you have to optimize.

Comment: "Shortly, it is not part that you have to optimize" but why should it be a part to ignore? I do optimizations where I can and I never like selecting from a database from another server, over a network data I do not need because in general, that is always a bottleneck, not a query generation on a local machine that can be reused once generated, never saw a case where that was a bottleneck, it always takes a split of a second to be generated.

Comment: So, find time and create github issue. If you care about micro performance you should never use EF.

Comment: "If you care about micro performance you should never use EF." again I disagree, I will always use it if I can and I don't need to drop EF because it can't accomplish everything I want. I've just asked a question if you know-how, that is all. But people often conflicting thoughts see as an attack on them. ;)

Comment: No worries. My English is not so good to be polite. I was just surprised about performance discussion in such minor case. I'm also developing LINQ provider for `linq2db` and you even cannot imagine which problems has to be solved to make it blazing fast.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I ran into a different problem with this approach. It seems OnModelCreating does not get called per each DbContext instance, making the query filter cache across them. Have you experienced such?

Comment: It is called ONCE per class type and options. Don't do any conditional things in `OnModelCreating`. Also create new question with new details.